# A bartender stole champagne from a bottle that contained 50% of

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A bartender stole champagne from a bottle that contained 50% of spirit and he replaced what he had stolen with champagne having 20% spirit. The bottle then contained only 25% spirit. How much of the bottle did he steal?

My approach: Let the total quantity champagne containing  (50% of the spirit) be x.

$\therefore$  it will contain x/2  spirit and x/2 non-spirit.

Suppose he steals y% from it. Let the total quantity of champagne containing(20 % of spirit) be z.

$\therefore$ It will contain z/5 spirit.

Now I'm not able to form an equation please help.

Comment: There is a problem with the premise. Like other wines, champagne typically has around 12% alcohol. 50% would be even stronger than whisky (which is around 40-45%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the fraction of volume that remains. So he stole $(1-x)$. Since volume stolen is replaced by 20% spirit, total volume of spirit now would be $(0.5x+(0.2\times(1-x))$. Since this is equal to 25% by volume, $(0.5x+(0.2\times(1-x)) = 0.25$. Thus $x = \frac{1}{6}$ and hence $\frac{5}{6}$th of the bottle was stolen.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the total volume of the spirit and let $w$ be the amount withdrawn and replaced.

Then we have that $$\frac{1}{2}(V-w)+\frac{1}{5}w=\frac{1}{4}V$$

Solving for $w$ gives $\frac{1}{4}V=\frac{3}{10}w\implies w=\frac{5}{6}V$

Answer (score 1):

Without (much) math.

Must steal enough champagne so that *weighted* average goes 5/6 of the way from 50 to 20 
(i.e. $[25-20] \times 5 = [50 - 25]$).

Therefore, he must steal 5/6 of the bottle.

I mention this approach not as a recommended approach for someone new to the problem, but rather as a way of developing intuition.

After enough experience with weighted average problems, they become solvable without (much) math.